# Wireframe for every single screen/page

Tags: web, automated-tests, frontend, wireframe

I am an automated-test engineer and call it occupational hazard, I keep thinking towards making automated testing efficient and easy.

Couple of weeks back, I was thinking, in fact just wondering, if we could introduce a new process where I force designers/developers to provide me a wireframe for every single or unique screen in the web application. 
Example: In a hypothetical web application, if home page displays differently for different profiles like associates, approvers, auditors and managers, I want a wireframe for each of those profiles. But if there are 2 managers (data combinations) in the organisation, I don't expect wireframe for these 2 managers as just data is changing and structure would remain same from automated-testing perspective.

This helps in automation in the following manner:

1. Say a sprint starts and it's decided that 2 new features shall be developed in this sprint.
2. Wireframes for these 2 new features shall be provided to the whole team at the begining of the sprint say in sprint-planning meeting.
3. Using these wireframes I would automate my testcases and when the actual screens are deployed, I would just run my automated-testcases. Of course they will fail due to some minor issues but they will be easy fixes. This is way better than not starting automation until the actual screen are deployed.

If this approach is possible, I will later demand for id and name properties of user controls (like links, buttons, edit boxs, check boxes, radio buttons etc) along with wireframes. I am aware that some teams are already sharing id and names properties of user controls with their automated-testing team upfront so that they can automate the testcases even before actual screens are deployed. You could say my idea is little enhanced version of that.

It sounded impractical so I stopped thinking towards it but later felt  like I should ask the community if it's possible? if yes, what's the overhead on the overall design/development team.

Some developers reading this might think that pffhhh... we are packed with stuffs already and this would be an overhead. But trust me. Early collaboration with testers and automate-testers would really help the quality of the application. So if the overhead is well within the limit, we could think towards introducing this process.

Please let me know your views.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding the related commands, code snippets or configuration infos... Otherwise your issue might be classified as off-topic as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Thanks.

Comment: possibly related to [automation testing using annotated wireframes](http://jchyip.blogspot.com/2006/12/automated-testing-using-annotated.html)

Comment: Hi Lloyd, it's more of a thought-process so I did not put any code. But I guess it was stupid of me to assume that everyone would know what's automated-testing or test-automation is. Apologies. I will update my question shortly with more details, if possible with some code snippets and some diagrams.